# Installing pandas on freeBSD

Tags: python, pandas, pip, freebsd

I am trying to install pandas on a freeBSD jail but it fails. I am a bit lost and don't know any further. The Full error-code is attached at the end.

Thoughts I allready have concerning this error:
I think I understand, that after running pip3 install pandas it is trying to install numpy but fails. I do not really understand this, since numpy is allready installed. When i run
`pip3 list` it returns
Therefore  I am guessing it is not checking at the right place? Or sth..

```
Package          Version
---------------- ---------
certifi          2020.6.20
chardet          3.0.4
Cython           0.29.21
idna             2.10
numpy            1.19.0
pip              20.1.1
pycosat          0.6.3
requests         2.24.0
ruamel.yaml      0.16.10
ruamel.yaml.clib 0.2.0
setuptools       49.1.0
urllib3          1.25.9
wget             3.2
```

If any further information on my system is needed, please let me know.

Thanks for any potential help ;-).

The full error :

```
      root@dash-app:/ # pip3 install pandas
    Collecting pandas
      Using cached pandas-1.0.5.tar.gz (5.0 MB)
      Installing build dependencies ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1vnawqu5/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.13' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
           cwd: None
      Complete output (142 lines):
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-49.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (789 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.13
        Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.13.3
        Using cached numpy-1.13.3.zip (5.0 MB)
      Using legacy setup.py install for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
      Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy
          Running setup.py install for numpy: started
          Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
           command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8u3hmxuq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1vnawqu5/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-1vnawqu5/overlay/include/python3.6m/numpy
               cwd: /tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/
          Complete output (119 lines):
          Running from numpy source directory.

          Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
          with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

            - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                     release)
            - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


          blas_opt_info:
          blas_mkl_info:
            libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            NOT AVAILABLE

          blis_info:
            libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            NOT AVAILABLE

          openblas_info:
            FOUND:
              libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
              library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
              language = c
              define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

            FOUND:
              libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
              library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
              language = c
              define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

          /bin/sh: svnversion: not found
          non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
          /bin/sh: svnversion: not found
          F2PY Version 2
          lapack_opt_info:
          lapack_mkl_info:
            libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
            NOT AVAILABLE

          openblas_lapack_info:
          customize UnixCCompiler
          C compiler: cc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC

          creating /tmp/tmpk303lrl9/tmp
          creating /tmp/tmpk303lrl9/tmp/tmpk303lrl9
          compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpk303lrl9/file.c.d -c'
          cc: /tmp/tmpk303lrl9/file.c

          C compiler: cc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC

          creating /tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_/tmp
          creating /tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_/tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_
          compile options: '-c'
          cc: /tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_/source.c

          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 58, in UnixCCompiler__compile
              extra_postargs, display = display)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 89, in <lambda>
              m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 152, in CCompiler_spawn
              raise DistutilsExecError('Command "%s" failed with exit status %d%s' % (cmd, s, msg))
          distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: Command "cc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -c /tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_/source.c -o /tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_/tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_/source.o" failed with exit status 127

          During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/setup.py", line 392, in <module>
              setup_package()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/setup.py", line 384, in setup_package
              setup(**metadata)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
              config = configuration()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/setup.py", line 166, in configuration
              config.add_subpackage('numpy')
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
              caller_level = 2)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
              caller_level = caller_level + 1)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
              config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
            File "numpy/setup.py", line 16, in configuration
              config.add_subpackage('linalg')
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
              caller_level = 2)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
              caller_level = caller_level + 1)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
              config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
            File "numpy/linalg/setup.py", line 29, in configuration
              lapack_info = get_info('lapack_opt', 0)  # and {}
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 380, in get_info
              return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 572, in get_info
              self.calc_info()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 1478, in calc_info
              openblas_info = get_info('openblas_lapack')
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 380, in get_info
              return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 572, in get_info
              self.calc_info()
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 1755, in calc_info
              if not self.check_embedded_lapack(info):
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 1790, in check_embedded_lapack
              obj = c.compile([src], output_dir=tmpdir)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 89, in <lambda>
              m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 343, in CCompiler_compile
              single_compile(o)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 303, in single_compile
              self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 89, in <lambda>
              m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
            File "/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/numpy/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 61, in UnixCCompiler__compile
              raise CompileError(msg)
          distutils.errors.CompileError: Command "cc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -c /tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_/source.c -o /tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_/tmp/tmpj0fwjhq_/source.o" failed with exit status 127
          ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rehauvzj/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8u3hmxuq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1vnawqu5/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-1vnawqu5/overlay/include/python3.6m/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
      ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1vnawqu5/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.13' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Any reason for not using official package `py37-pandas`?

Comment: Yes - it crashes aswell .. stating that something is wrong with my numpy installation. I allready tried to reinstall numpy - but it doesn't work either

Comment: Crashes with what error? Also, what FreeBSD version are you using?

Comment: The installation for pandas doesn't crash. But when I try to import pandas in python it states, that i am trying to import a failed installation of numpy. I tried to reinstall but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am running: FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE-p15

Comment: 11.2 is not supported anymore. Try upgrading to `11.4` at least and then trying the official package again.

Comment: thank you for your help. I will try and report in, when i am done

Comment: Updating to 11.4 solved the issue! Thank you very much!